# listview not updating when navigating back to page in winrt phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, lazy-loading

I have a page in my application which contains a listview, listview is binded with an observeable collection like this

```
public ObservableCollection<ViolationsByPlateViewModel> ViolationAssigned;
...
...
...
defaultViewModel.Add("ViolationList", ViolationAssigned);

ItemsSource="{Binding ViolationList, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

And defined this in page contructor

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

I am updating my Violation assigned variable after every time I hit bottom of my listview. And it works fine. but when I click on my item and go to second screen and came back to first screen again. I found out that my list is not updating when I hit bottom of the screen. I tried debugging and found out that my variable is still updating but not updating at UI. It seems that data is not binded anymore and listview populating from the cache.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We found the WinRT page cache to be pretty finicky when navigating backwards in certain situations. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. To get around this, without having to debug too much into a problem we care little about, we switched our paging to use MtFrame and MtPage from [MyToolkit](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit). This has worked out pretty well for us in a number of areas in our app, but especially in paging.